# Make a line that connects 2 cells in a table symmetric

Tags: javascript, html

```
function connectThem() {    
            alert('(' + markedCells[0] +') и (' + markedCells[1] + ')');

            if (markedCells.length == 2) {
                y_distance = markedCells[0][0] - markedCells[1][0];
                y_distance = Math.abs(y_distance) + 1;  // vertical distance between dots

                x_distance = markedCells[0][1] - markedCells[1][1];
                x_distance = Math.abs(x_distance) + 1;  // horizontal distance between dots


                if (x_distance > y_distance) {  // if horizontal distance is bigger than vertical distance
                    markedCells.sort(function(a,b){return a[1] - b[1];});

                    totalRows = y_distance;

                    for (var row = 0 ; row < y_distance; row++) {
                        thisRowLength = Math.floor(x_distance / totalRows);

                        for (var c = 0; c < thisRowLength; c++) {
                            document.getElementById('cell-' + markedCells[0][0] + '-' + markedCells[0][1]).style.backgroundColor = "red";

                            markedCells[0][1] = parseInt(markedCells[0][1]) + 1;
                        }

                        if (markedCells[0][0] < markedCells[1][0]) {    // if first marked dot is higher
                            markedCells[0][0] = parseInt(markedCells[0][0]) + 1;
                        }
                        else {                                          // if second one is higher 
                            markedCells[0][0] = parseInt(markedCells[0][0]) - 1;
                        }

                        totalRows -= 1; // vertical remaining
                        x_distance -= thisRowLength;    // horizontal remaining
                    }  
                }

                else {
                    markedCells.sort(function(a,b){return a[0] - b[0];});

                    totalCols = x_distance;

                    for (var col = 0; col < x_distance; col++) {
                        thisColLength = Math.floor(y_distance/totalCols);

                        for (var r = 0; r < thisColLength; r++) {

                            document.getElementById('cell-' + markedCells[0][0] + '-' + markedCells[0][1]).style.backgroundColor = "red";

                            markedCells[0][0] = parseInt(markedCells[0][0]) + 1;
                        }


                        if (markedCells[0][1] < markedCells[1][1]) {    // if first marked dot is higher
                            markedCells[0][1] = parseInt(markedCells[0][1]) + 1;
                        }
                        else {  // if second one is higher
                            markedCells[0][1] = parseInt(markedCells[0][1]) - 1;
                        }


                        totalCols -= 1;
                        y_distance -= thisColLength;
                    }
                }
            }

            else {  // if more or less than 2 dots to connect
                alert("Can't connect " + markedCells.length + " dots");
            }  
        }
```

This is my ugly code that does the following thing: I mark 2 cells in a table and the script connects those 2 cells with a line - coloring the path cell by cell. Even if it's a lame solution it still works fine. But! The line is asymmetric.

[image]

As you can see the upper part has 2-cell lines but the bottom one has 3-cell lines. And it looks assymetric. I want it to add 3-cell lines in the middle of the connecting line or near the ends of the connecting line. How do I do that? Or maybe what is the better solution for connecting cells?

Comment: `This is my ugly code` you forgot to add the code..

Comment: I don't see any HTML but it looks like you do NOT connect them, you just add some background color. Why don't you do it with only  CSS?

Comment: @caramba I mean visual connection. And how do I do it with only CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Cause you also asked for other solutions, this is one (based on my comment, which I wonder if it really would work (dind't manage to do it with only CSS though)) but to give you an idea here's an example using javascript and CSS ...

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
var styles = '';
rows.forEach((element, index) => {
var rowNr = (index +1);
var cellNr = (index+index +1);
styles = styles + 'tr:nth-child('+rowNr+') td:nth-child('+cellNr+'),tr:nth-child('+rowNr+') td:nth-child('+(cellNr+1)+') { background: red;}'
});
styleElement.innerHTML = styles;
document.body.appendChild(styleElement);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
/* unfortunately this didn't work but shows the logic needed */
/*
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1),
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3),
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) {
  background: blue;
}
*/
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[If you want to play with it here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxg5waet/)